# Extra row when floating divs

Tags: css, html, grid, css-float, rows

Why oh why do I see this extra row in my grid? I'm using the `float:left` property and percentage widths for each grid container. The markup for each container is part of a WordPress loop, so inserting a `clear:both` every 4th container isn't easily done. Help!

[See the problem in action here.](http://luckylab.worksdev.com/shop)

Comment: I added a counter and used modulus to insert <div class="clear"></div> every 4th box. This helps, but the 1st box is still on it's own row. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

You have a div with clear:both between first and second content4col.

As a side note, instead of using clear every fourth element you could use box-sizing: border-box to include padding and borders "inside" of your box model.

(EDIT: somehow the editor is not working, so I cannot make my answer look good.)

Comment: Indeed I do! For whatever reason, `<?php if ($count%4 == 1) echo '<div class="clear"></div>';?>` is dropping clear div right after the first instance of the loop... then ever 4th instance. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you could change it to <?php if ($count % 4 == 0) echo '<div class="clear"></div>';?>.  But that doesn't solve the underlying problem.  (Unfortunately it's challenging to actually solve the underlying problem since the original version is no longer available...)